# Text looks blurry on some devices and browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know how to fix fuzzy/blurry on some devices and browsers?

When I check page on two different computers, on first everything is clear and on second text look a bit blurry.

Browsers - Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Could you post screenshots of the blurry text and your code?

Comment: @VikrantSingh says "*you can try playing around with the <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp">font-weight</a>, <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_letter-spacing.asp">letter-spacing</a>, or try using a different -- narrower maybe -- font.*"

Comment: Can it be dual monitor issue, when you drag the browser instance from one screen to another??